# SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error [Create query] How to pass dynamic value [CREATE USER :user ]

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

SQL query:  CREATE USER "test@gmail.COM" DISPLAY_NAME="TIMOTHY SMITH" FIRST_NAME="TIM"

@Query(value = "CREATE USER :user DISPLAY_NAME=:displayName FIRST_NAME=:firstName", nativeQuery = true)
void createAccount(String user, String displayName, String firstName);

Error:

```
    Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 11 unexpected '='.
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowExceptionSub(SnowflakeUtil.java:124)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:64)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.pollForOutput(StmtUtil.java:434)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.execute(StmtUtil.java:338)
```

Comment: Can you add a little more context?

Comment: ** Getting below error with :user (statement )

** Issue with :user statement -->  CREATE USER "test@gmail.COM" with CREATE USER :user

SQL query: CREATE USER "test@gmail.COM" DISPLAY_NAME="TIMOTHY SMITH" FIRST_NAME="TIM"

Comment: Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 12 unexpected '?'.

Comment: The code part you show is from JPA, but how do you execute this via JDBC? Can you provide maybe full code?